# MYSQL passing string into IN operator not working in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

by right `SELECT topicFollowed FROM User WHERE id = 10000)` return "[0,2]" <<-string

but when i execute `SELECT *  from News WHERE topicId IN (SELECT topicFollowed FROM User WHERE id = 10000)` only 0 is pass in and 2 is not. i cant figure out why. it only return topicId that is 0

Answer (score 1):

Your `IN` list consists of *exactly* one item, a string of the form `'[0,2]'`.  If that is what `topicId` looks like, then your query will work.

In other words, you have a problem with your data structure.  You shouldn't be storing lists of things in strings.  The proper data structure would have two rows, one for each of the ids in the list.

Sometimes, you are stuck with someone else's bad data design.  You can do what you want, by doing something like this:

```
SELECT n.*
from News n
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM user u
              WHERE find_in_set(topicId, replace(replace(topicFollowed, '[', ''), ']', '') AND
                    id = 10000
             );
```

Comment: I am storing array in varchar, is this the correct way or there is a better way to do this?

Comment: @phongyewtong . . . Yes, use a junction table, with one row per id and one row per topic id.